# Strict mime type error in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript

I have the project on Angular 5.x
Trying to import [this editor](https://github.com/fxmontigny/ng2-ace-editor)

It's the TypeScript wrapper above the well-known [Ace editor](https://ace.c9.io/)

Editor works, I see it in my project and everything is fine. Until I try to change some settings. Default language is SQL. I need to edit JSON. So I use syntax like this:

```
<div
  ace-editor
  [(text)]="json"
  [mode]="'json'"
  [theme]="'eclipse'"
  [readOnly]="false"
  [autoUpdateContent]="true"
  [durationBeforeCallback]="1000"
></div>
```

and getting the following error in the browser's console (Chrome, latest):

> Refused to execute script from 'http://localhost:4200/mode-json.js'
>   because its MIME type ('text/html') is not executable, and strict MIME
>   type checking is enabled.

The following lines are added into the `.angular-cli.json` file:

```
scripts: [
  "../node_modules/ace-builds/src-min/ace.js",
  "../node_modules/ace-builds/src-min/theme-eclipse.js"
]
```

So... Can somebody give me an answer how can I solve this issue without a crutches?

Comment: found any solution buddy i am also getting the same errir

Comment: I stopped looking for a solution long time ago. No idea how to solve it